# How do I display the code as "you have 1 more attempt" instead of displaying "you have 2 more attempts" twice?

Tags: python

The issue I have is that it displays you have 2 more attempts twice after the first attempt. How do I edit the code, so that it displays: "you have 2 more attempts" and "you have 1 more attempt"?

```
answer_count = 0
answer_limit = 3
while answer_count < answer_limit:
answer = input('what is 2 + 2? ') 
answer_count +=1
if answer != "4":
    print('incorrect, you have 2 more attempts') 
elif answer == "4":
    print('correct')
    break
else:
    print('sorry you are out of attempts')
```

Comment: Please post your code _exactly_ as you have it, including the correct indentation.

Comment: Use the values of `answer_limit` and `answer_count`

Answer (score 2):

Use the value of  `answer_limit - answer_count` in your print statement:

```
print('incorrect, you have ' + str(answer_limit - answer_count) + ' more attempts')
```

The str() function converts the answer into a string so it can be printed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
answer_count = 0
answer_limit = 3
while (answer_count < answer_limit):
    answer = input('what is 2 + 2? ')
    answer_count +=1
    if answer != "4":
        print('incorrect, you have {} more attempts'.format(answer_limit-answer_count))
    elif answer == "4":
        print('correct')
        break

if answer != "4":
    print('sorry you are out of attempts')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
answer_count = 0
answer_limit = 3
answers_left = answer_limit
while answer_count < answer_limit:
    answer = input('what is 2 + 2? ') 
    answer_count +=1
    answers_left -= 1
    if answer != "4":
        print('incorrect, you have '+ str(answers_left) +' more attempts') 
    else:
        print('correct')
        break
else:
    print('sorry you are out of attempts')
```

I added an `answers_left` variable which after each attempt it takes one out from answer_limit

Comment: You could also turn that redundant `elif` into an `else`. The two conditions are the inverse of each other.

Comment: Don't you want to be converting `answers_left` into a string in the `print` statement? I think you're going to get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Thank you , Corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

```
answer_limit = 3
while answer_limit > 0:
  answer = input('what is 2 + 2? ') 
  if answer == "4":
    print('correct')
    exit()
  else:
    answer_limit -= 1
    print ('incorrect, you have %s more attempts' % answer_limit)

print('sorry you are out of attempts')
```